# Inequality about rank of matrix and submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be a block matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix}B_1\\B_2\\\end{pmatrix}$.
I need to prove that $rank\,B\le rank\,B_1 +rank\,B_2$.

I think this inequality is intuitively true but it is hard for me to write down the proof. Let $B$ be size $(m_1 + m_2)\times n$, $B_2$ be size $m_1\times n$ and $B_2$ be size $m_2\times n$.

I know $rank\,B\le\min\,\{m_1+m_2,n\},\, rank\,B_1\le\min\{m_1,n\}\,$ and $rank\,B_2\le\min\{m_2,n\}$. So $rank\,B_1\,+rank\,B_2\le\min\{m_1,n\}\,+\,\min\{m_2,n\}$. I cannot deduce that $rank\,B\le rank\,B_1 +rank\,B_2$. I also thought about the definition of rank of a matrix. But it doesn't really help. Any hint about this question?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  The most straightforward that I can think of is to note that the rank of $B$ is equal to the size of the largest possible linearly independent set of rows of $B$. Any set of linearly independent rows of $B$ is the union of a linearly independent set of rows of $B_1$ and a linearly independent set of rows of $B_2$.